# Будет ли считаться нарушением? (DI)

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, di

Создаю для себя проект и задался вопросом: будет ли считаться следующий код нарушением какой-либо концепции?

Проект делаю с использованием prism. Есть базовый класс NavigationViewModelBase. В наследуемых классах будет использоваться IRegionManager, который я получаю через DI. Пока таких классов немного, но в будущем код разрастется. И я подумал зачем мне в каждом наследуемом классе явно указывать новое поле с IRegionManager и получать его через конструктор, если это можно сделать в базовом NavigationViewModelBase?

*Примеры:*

**Как есть сейчас:**

ViewModelA.cs

```
private IRegionManager _regionManager;

public ViewModelA(IRegionManager _regionManager)
{
    _regionManager = regionManager;
}

private void SomeMethod() 
{
    _regionManager.RequestNavigate("...."); 
}
```

**Что думаю сделать:**

NavigationViewModelBase.cs

```
protected IRegionManager RegionManager { get; }

public NavigationViewModelBase() 
{
    var container = ((PrismApplicationBase)Application.Current).Container;
    RegionManager = container.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
}
```

ViewModelA.cs

```
private void SomeMethod() 
{
    RegionManager.RequestNavigate("....");  
}
```

Comment: Так получается сервис-локатор. Он давно считается антипаттерном. Потому что код гвоздями приколочен к определённому контейнеру и чтобы сменить его на другой, нужно изменять весь код.

Comment: Попробуйте написать модульные тесты. Получается их сделать? Оставляйте так. Не получается легко замокать? Значит, следует вернуться к нормальному DI.

Comment: любой код нарушает какую-нибудь концепцию

Comment: непонятно, зачем получать контейнер, если в базовом классе точно так же можно получать параметром в конструкторе. При этом определение общего поля точно так же останется в базовом классе